# Invalid HTTP response when sending a zip file from a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am attempt to create a zip file in memory, from multiple other zip files read from file streams. It appears that it is able to read the files correctly, and create a zip file; however, when the response is being created all content headers get placed into `invalidHeaders`. This causes the download to never occur, and instead a bad response page is loaded.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Gather all zips into a single zip file 
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach(var zipFile in zipFiles)
        {
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(zipFile.ZipFilePath, Path.GetFileName(zipFile.ZipFilePath));
        }             
    }
    // Now we have our memory stream with our zip
    HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    message.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
    message.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    message.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "AllZIPFiles.zip";
    message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
    message.Content.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;
    // Content headers placed into invalidHeaders?
    return ResponseMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: Try to set the position of the memory stream to 0 after you create the zip file like this: `memoryStream.Position = 0;`

Comment: Yep that was it, setting the memory stream back before setting the content does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `ZipArchive` does its work, the position of the stream will be at the end of the stream.

Before sending such stream as a response, make sure that you set the stream position to 0 like this:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```